# Git - проверка подключения

Tags: git

Доброго времени всем.
Начинаю вникать в Git, ( винда->обновление удаленного репозитория ). Возник вопрос - как проверить, что свеже сделанное подключение SSH работает?? Именно не GitHub, а репозиторий размещенный на "своем" сервере.

Буду благодарен за конкретные ссылки в тему

Comment: какой сервер установлен?

Comment: точно так же, как и в случае с сервером github.com. протокол-то один и тот же: `ssh пользователь@сервер`

Comment: лучше сразу `ssh -T git@server` (да, пользователь обычно git). В большинстве случаев эта команда выведет в терминал "привет имярек, все ок"